# element style doesn't change on click react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using framer motion to create slider in react.. and I want when button clicked translateX reset to 0

the problem is when I click to the buttin first time nothing happed but when I click again it's back to 0 as I want

```
 const handleClick = (key, item) => {
    innerSlide.current.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "transform:translateX(0px) !important"
    );
    // innerSlide.current.computedStyleMap().get("transform")[0].x.value = 0;
    setSelected(key);
    setSelectedDish(item);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the important! rule?
You can't directly use !important with the setAttribute method in JavaScript. It's because setAttribute manipulates the HTML attribute and HTML style attributes do not understand !important.